# Can Magento really handle asynchronous execution of events?

Tags: event-observer

The Swiftotter Magento developer Study guide states concerning Observers:

> Event data should be able to be
>   stored and then run in a queue at a later time.

Is this correct? Do I really have to assume that my events observers are ran in a asynchronous way at a later time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depends how you look at it. Magento is (MySQL) transactional which means things are getting queued whilst tables are locked. They are then processed in a first come first serves basis when locks are released. Observers would also work on this basis. I don't believe community edition has anything more complex then that. I've read about enterprise edition having what's essentially a worker queue. But I think in this context that's what they mean.

Answer (score 1):

> Do I really have to assume that my events observers are ran in a asynchronous way at a later time?

Event observers could be executed later (likely at the end of your request/response cycle) however note that they would still be in your "main" process.

Truly asynchronous would mean that you execute the observer code in an entirely different thread or process. It's not natively supported, although Magento does provide all the necessary tooling to do it yourself.

With Magento, you already get a message broker and a consumer out of the box.

At some point you will have to place a message in your queue and then process this using a queue consumer.

This works but quickly becomes cumbersome because each asynchronous event will need it's own queue consumer and topic. Eventually, you will some way to abstract this away for you such that you're only declaring code to execute something asynchronously.

Here's an example module that can execute code asynchronously in the way you'd expect. (Disclaimer: I'm the author of this module)

https://github.com/aligent/magento-async-events

Answer (score 0):

I also found this now in the dev docs:

https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/coding-standards/technical-guidelines.html#14-events

> 14.1. All values (including objects) passed to an event MUST NOT be modified in the event observer. Instead, plugins SHOULD BE used for modifying the input or output of a function.

So I think if we follow this rule, events could really be executed asynchronously.